# Nodejs npm mssql SQLDbType.Structured?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, node-mssql, tedious

I am using npm mssql and I need to pass an SQLDbType.Structured parameter, is there a mapping for this type?

**Update:**

> NodeJS connecting to SQL Server 2008 or later.

Answer (score 1):

Table value parameters was added both to **tedious** and **mssql** recently.

Here is the documentation on how to do it from **node-mssql** (added to version ^0.5.1):

```
var tvp = new sql.Table()

// Columns must correspond with type we have created in database.
tvp.columns.add('a', sql.VarChar(50));
tvp.columns.add('b', sql.Int);

// Add rows
tvp.rows.add('hello tvp', 777); // Values are in same order as columns.
```